# Resizing a std::vector using move insertion and copy insertion

Tags: c++, stdvector, move-semantics

In the C++ standard [vector.capacity](https://wg21.link/N4861) section, it defines two overloads for `resize()`. (see also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize)

This overload requires that the type T is `MoveInsertable` and `DefaultInsertable`:

```cpp
constexpr void resize(size_type sz);
```

The other overload requires that the type T is `CopyInsertable`:

```cpp
constexpr void resize(size_type sz, const T& c);
```

My question is that why doesn't the second overload try to **move** from the existing values from the old vector, and further copy-insert new values from the supplied `c` argument. Wouldn't that be more efficient?

Comment: It might move from the old to the new (probably does if it can) but the fill value (`c`) has to be copied so `T` has to be `CopyInsertable`.

Comment: You can't move from `const T& c`, only from `T&& c`. And this, depending on move semantics of `T` will move `c` to first new element, then all other elements can only be initialized with "moved from" `c`.

Comment: counter question: How often can you move from `c` before it is unusable because it is a moved from object in unspecified state?

Comment: Who says it _doesn't_ do that...? It might well do so for existing elements. It can't for the fill value, for obvious reasons already given. It's unclear what the question really is.

Comment: on a second read I am not sure anymore if I understood the question correctly. Are you asking about the elements that already were present in the vector before the resize? I would expect that they are moved when possible, but thats orthogonal to how the new elements are created

Comment: at some point `resize(size_type sz, ??? c)` has to make a copy (unless `new size == old size + 1`), thats why it requires `CopyInsertable`, that does not exclude that it will also exploit weaker constraints when they do apply

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Because the standard states for the first overload that *... If an exception is thrown other than by the move constructor of a non-Cpp17CopyInsertable T there are no effects.* But for the second overload: *If an exception is thrown there are no effects.* That's probably my misunderstanding though.

Comment: @XIv thats an interesting detail. I think you should have added that to the question. Though it is not nice to change the question substantially once you got answers (and accepted one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that the second parameter could be an rvalue reference - this saves one copy, when it is subsequently copied from the first newly appended item. I assume what you have in mind is something like this:

```
std::vector<LargeObject> v;

// ...

LargeObject obj = setupLotsOfResources();

// Now do 1 move and 9 copies instead of 10 copies
v.resize(10, std::move(obj));
```

However, I would consider this an edge case, and working with rvalue references that are used for 1 move construction and N-1 copies is quite a confusing API. As you are free to use the `std::vector` API with what is already there such that for the above example, you will have 1 move and N-1 copies, I believe the rationale behind the existing function signature is ease of use and a straightforward signature that doesn't require much studying of the specs to understand what it does.

Comment: my guess was also that its a trade-off between that one copy and clarity of the interface. `void resize(size_type sz, T&& c);` can be easily misunderstood as making no copies

Comment: Uh yeah that's exactly what I was trying to express. Seems to be not clear in the answer

Comment: nono, it is clear. Just wasnt 100% sure if thats what you mean, though I also wouldn't know what else that last paragraph would refer to if not that

Comment: Ok, we can just leave the comments here then for when it hasn't become clear enough, they'll help :)